# NEEvaluateConnectionRule to match all internet traffic

Tags: ios, sdk, connection, vpn

I try to create a NEEvaluateConnectionRule that will connect if needed for all internet traffic.

```
 let connectionRule = NEEvaluateConnectionRule(
            matchDomains: [""],
            andAction: .connectIfNeeded
        )
```

If in matchDomains I set "google.com" my VPN will connect only in case I want to access google.com, but I want to create a connection rule that will connect to all internet traffic.

Any suggestion/link is well come.

Comment: Did you fix that? I have the same problem. Thanks.